# What is the best practice for gendering in a professional context right now?

Tags: political-correctness, gender-neutrality

I know Binnen-I used to be a thing, but I am also seeing some other practices like the [Gendergap](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendergap_(Linguistik)).

Which one is the currently least controversial and most widely accepted?

Comment: The answer depends on whom you ask and where you ask himEr :-) . The form "BesucherInnen" ([Binnen-I](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binnen-I)) was used extensively about five years go. Nowadays I do not see it so often anymore. Compared to using Gendergab or only the female version, the Binnen-I is probably less controversial one because it interrupts the reading flow less than the Gendergap. Using the female version only, expresses a political position (from my personal feeling): strong feminist or left-wing. The usage considerably depends on the context.

Comment: Gendering ist unprofessionell, da es auf einem Missverständnis basiert, wie Geschlecht in der Sprache funktioniert.

Comment: @userunknown - Das andere Missverständnis (genau wie bei PC) ist die irrige Annahme, dass der Einfluss von Gesinnung auf Sprache auch umgekehrt funktionieren würde.

Answer (score 4):

Using proper words, i.e. both male and female terms at all times.

Comment: Right. If you want to change something, don't change the words used, change the mindsets...

Comment: Or genderneutral forms,  such as "Studierende"  (at least that is what my university recommended)

Comment: A point can be made that _Studierende_ is not a full synonym of _Studenten und Studentinnen_: only those studying right now (in a library, say) would actually be _Studierende_. So, least controversial? Use both forms.

Comment: I agree, but think that this is a bit short for an answer.